# Extending Doob’s optional stopping time

Tags: measure-theory, martingales

Let $\tau \geq 0$ be a stopping time, $\mathbb{E} \tau<\infty$.
(b) Based on the identity
$$
\left|X_{\tau \wedge n}-X_0\right|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\left(X_k-X_{k-1}\right) \cdot \mathbf{1}\{\tau \geq k\}\right| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|X_k-X_{k-1}\right| \cdot \mathbf{1}\{\tau \geq k\}
$$
and the proof of Doob's Optional Stopping Theorem, part (iii), show the following: If $X$ is a supermartingale for which there exists a $C \in \mathbb{R}$ with
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\left|X_k-X_{k-1}\right| \mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1}\right) \leq C \quad \forall k>0, \text { a.s. },
$$
then $\mathbb{E} X_\tau \leq \mathbb{E} X_0$. Of course we have equality in case $X$ is a martingale.

Could someone verify if I have the right idea for this solution:

$\textbf{b)}$ From the tower rule $$\mathbb{E}\left(\left|X_k-X_{k-1}\right| \mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1}\right) \leq C \implies \mathbb{E}\left(\left|X_k-X_{k-1} \right|\right) \leq \mathbb{E}\left(C \right)= C.$$
$$\left|X_{\tau \wedge n}-X_0\right|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\tau \wedge n}\left(X_k-X_{k-1}\right) \cdot \mathbf{1}\{\tau \geq k\}\right| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\tau \wedge n}\left|X_k-X_{k-1}\right|$$

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\tau \wedge n}\left|X_k-X_{k-1}\right| \right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\tau \wedge n} \mathbb{E} \left( \left|X_k-X_{k-1}\right| \right) \leq (\tau \wedge n) \cdot C$$
$\left|X_{\tau \wedge n}-X_0\right|$ is bounded by an integrable function (a constant function where the measure is finite) and so we can use dominated convergence:

$$0 \geq \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left(X_{T \wedge n}-X_0\right)=\mathbb{E} X_\tau-\mathbb{E} X_0$$

I've seen other solutions where they take the expectation of the inequality including the indicator function but would I be right in that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|X_k-X_{k-1}\right| \cdot \mathbf{1}\{\tau \geq k\} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|X_k-X_{k-1}\right|$$?

Comment: John's answer is of course right, but just to point out the issues in the question: 1. you're equating a deterministic quantity $\mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\tau \wedge n}\left|X_k-X_{k-1}\right| \right)$ with a random variable $\sum_{k=1}^{\tau \wedge n} \mathbb{E} \left( \left|X_k-X_{k-1}\right| \right),$ and the latter is almost definitely not a constant a.s., so this is incorrect (note that $\tau$ is random). 2. the final inequality is of course correct, but it doesn't help with the question, since $n$ is unbounded. You need some tail of $\tau$ in there to use its finite expectation.

Comment: thank you I see where I've gone wrong with not remembering the stopping time is random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stopping time $\tau$ shouldn't be outside the expectation (as you have it in the third displayed formula of **b)**.)
Rather use
$$
\Bbb E\left(|X_k-X_{k-1}|\cdot 1_{\{\tau\ge k\}}\right)
=\Bbb E\left(\Bbb E\left(|X_k-X_{k-1}|\mid\mathcal F_{k-1}\right)\cdot 1_{\{\tau\ge k\}}\right)\le C\Bbb P[\tau\ge k],
$$
because $\{\tau\ge k\}=\{\tau\le k-1\}^c$ for $k\ge 1$. Now use the *tail-sum formula* $\Bbb E[\tau]=\sum_{k\ge 1}\Bbb P[\tau\ge k]$.